# Should glues actually be adhesives?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

So we have [glue](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/glue). Currently I am seeing if we should pluralize it but aside from that ....

I wanted to tag [How to clean off spray adhesive?](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/300/how-to-clean-off-spray-adhesive) with [glue](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/glue) as it seems very appropriate to me.

Should we have [adhesives](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adhesives) where [glue](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/glue) would be a synonym? or

Should we have [glue](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/glue) and [adhesives](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adhesives) would be the synonym?

or perhaps [adhesives](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adhesives) would be considered something different?

Comment: Off hand, I guess I'm thinking that adhesive actually includes much more: tape, putty, pastes, etc. So I guess glue is an adhesive, but not all adhesives are glue. To me, though, it's a question of whether or not we'll need separate tags for those (which I don't know).

Comment: @CreationEdge Good point. Where do spray adhesives fit into that. `Adhesives` _might_ be too broad then.....

Answer (score 4):

Just by definition Adhesives is more encompassing and includes glues.

**Adhesive** - a substance used for sticking objects or materials together

So this stands to reason that Adhesives would include glue, tape, paste or whatever else one uses to stick items together.

I think Adhesives is probably a better tag than Glue since having a Glue tag would mean we need a Tape tag and I don't see that being very widely used.

Comment: Currently, we think ["tools" is too broad](http://meta.crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/78/tools-tag-is-too-broad-should-it-be-removed-blacklisted), but I agree that most sub-types won't be used. I think "adhesive(s)" is the way to go, but we should allow subtypes, such as "epoxy", if we get enough questions on those specific materials.

Answer (score 2):

The synonym was suggested, but it doesn't seem that there was enough people to vote on it.

Don't worry, **I made it stick!**

I merged glue -> adhesives and made them a synonym.

We can still use specialty adhesives where necessary, such as epoxy, if they come up.

Comment: Hahaha very punny